# Automatically trim string if it is too long on insert/update

Tags: java, sql, h2

I've got an application which gets data from the web and inserts it into a H2 DB. On rare occasions, the value being inserted is bigger then the SQL column size. In these cases I'd like to automatically trim the end of the value (at least for strings). I don't care about data loss as it only concerns informational values shown to the end user.

Info:
 - For MySQL I've found the STRICT parameter ([Automatically trimming length of string submitted to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186343/automatically-trimming-length-of-string-submitted-to-mysql)). Is there an equivalent parameter for h2 I didn't find?
 - I'd like to avoid having to check the string length in code as it potentially affects many fields.

System:
 - OS: win/osx/linux
 - DB: [h2](http://www.h2database.com/) embedded 1.3.173 (could be updated to latest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a wrapper over PreaparedStatement and truncate long strings there

```
...

public void setString(int i, String str) {
    str = str.length() > max ? str.substring(0, max) : str;
    target.setString(str, i);
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I'd like to avoid having to do this on the java side as 1) the max length is usually respected (out of 1300 queries 1 returns a string which is too long) and 2) ~40 fields would require this check

Comment: As the magic h2 switch doesn't seem to exist, I'll go with your proposition. Thanks.