# MySQL Configuration to auto truncate decimal value

Tags: mysql

I've a table with a field `DECIMAL(9,2)` and I've 2 servers running both mysql 5.7

If I run this code

```
INSERT INTO `money_accounts` (`balance`) VALUES (9999999999.99);
```

On one of the servers it got inserted and value is truncated, on the other it raise a `Out of range value for column balance` error.

My question is, what is the configuration value that makes this happen? or why it's happening in one server and not in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we read the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

> When MySQL stores a value in a numeric column that is outside the
>   permissible range of the column data type, the result depends on the
>   SQL mode in effect at the time
>
> If strict SQL mode is enabled, MySQL rejects the out-of-range value
>   with an error, and the insert fails, in accordance with the SQL
>   standard.
>
> If no restrictive modes are enabled, MySQL clips the value to the
>   appropriate endpoint of the range and stores the resulting value
>   instead.

So it means that You should set necessary sql mode that will not fail when out-of-range error happens.

There is no config parameter about that.

And resolution of same issue we can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459184/mysql-too-long-varchar-truncation-error-setting) that says that disabling `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` modes can fix Your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The definition

```
DECIMAL(9,2)
```

means 9 digits of *total* precision, with 2 digits *after* the decimal place.  The value

```
9999999999.99
```

has 12 total digits of precision, with 2 after the decimal place.  Hence, the value is out of range.  Rightfully, MySQL should have thrown an out of range error in both cases.  In the case where it "worked," my guess is that truncation occurred.

By the way, you should be using `DECIMAL(12,2)` or wider to store the value in your question.

**Update:**

One possible explanation for why one of your servers was doing the insertion while the other failed is that the first has traditional mode turned off.  Run the following on both servers:

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode
```

If you see output looking like

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, STRICT_ALL_TABLES, ...
```

then the server is running in traditional mode, which means it won't truncate but will reject.  To turn it off, try running

```
SET SESSION sql_mode=''
```

and them the insert should succeed (with truncation).  But in any case, you should *not* be relying on truncation in production.  If you need more precision, then widen the column.

Reference: [Automatically trimming length of string submitted to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186343/automatically-trimming-length-of-string-submitted-to-mysql)

Comment: yes.. i know that, the question is why on un server it worked, I want to know the configuration value that makes the autotruncation, i'm not able to find it in mysql variables or documentation.